# Is there a way to use a facet and a plain text in logs search on Datadog?

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

For some reason unknown to me, when I use a facet and just plain text search on datadog, no logs come up (image below). But when I remove either the facet or the text, I get logs.

[image]

I'm trying to combine the two for a dashboard. I've gone through the documentation briefly and I don't see anything stating that I can't do this